# dojox/mobile/Uploader error if the content where the widget is placed is dojox/mobile/

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

Im getting this error when i try to upload images from mobile device.

I have to upload 2 times the same image before is getting uploaded

```
2scrollable.js:617 
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 
'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, 
which may only be programmatically set to the empty
 string.lang.extend._keepInputCaretInActiveElement 
    @ scrollable.js:617lang.extend.onFlickAnimationEnd
 @ scrollable.js:398(anonymous function) @ lang.js:384
```

Comment: Please post some code if you want some help

Comment: try to test it here   [http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.6/dojo-release-1.9.6/dojox/mobile/tests/test_ScrollableView-HTML-inputs.html]